# How to get catch after retryWhen?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

I want to retry `get` request a few times with a second delay in case of error, but if all attemps failed, then execute error handler.

Following code retryes request, but catch is never executed. How can I fix it?

```
import {Response, Http} from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

```
this.http.get("/api/getData").map(data => {
  console.log('get')
  return data.json()
})
.retryWhen(err => {
  console.log('retry')
  return err.delay(1000).take(5)
})
.catch(err => {
  console.log('catch')
  this.handleHttpError(err)
  return err
})
.subscribe(data => {
  console.log('subscribe')
  console.log(data)
})
```

Comment: There's an example of retrying a few times in [the docs](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/retrywhen.md), and it looks a bit different. Have you tried that?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, can't combine their examples to make it working right...

Comment: Well 1. I don't think `.take(5)` inside the retry will help at all, and 2. have you tried using the second callback to `.subscribe` rather than adding a `.catch`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, my example makes correct number of attempts, but never calls `catch`. Their example with `take` after `retryWhen` makes an infinite number of requests.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, actually I have catch and subscribe in different layers of application, so that's not a good idea to add a error callback there.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem here is that when the notification Observable returned from the callback in `retryWhen` sends the `complete` notification it's propagated further as `complete` which is not what you want from your description.

You want to send it as `error` notification which means you can't use `take()` and use some other operator to rethrow the error.

For example like this:

```
Observable.defer(() => Observable.throw("It's broken"))
  .retryWhen(err => {
    console.log('retry');
    let retries = 0;
    return err
      .delay(1000)
      .map(error => {
        if (retries++ === 5) {
          throw error;
        }
        return error;
      });
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('catch');
    return Observable.of(err);
  })
  .subscribe(data => {
    console.log('subscribe');
    console.log(data);
  });
```

You can count the number of retries in the `retries` variable yourself and if it reaches some limit just rethrow the error. The `map()` operator wraps all callbacks with try-catch blocks so any error thrown in its callable is going to be sent as `error` signal.

Comment: What do you think about `take` - `concat` - `throw`?

Comment: What about them?

Comment: I mean the other solution I found. Could you please compare it with yours. Are there some reasons to prefer one of them?

Comment: With you solution be aware that you're not able to get the error that caused the `retryWhen`. You're using `Observable.throw(err)` which means you're throwing an Observable object as an error (`err` is an Observable) which probably doesn't make sense. However if you don't care about the error object you can definitely use it.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> return err.delay(1000).take(5)
> ```

There should be a error after retries, for example:

```
return err.delay(1000).take(5).concat(Observable.throw(err))
```

**Thanks [@martin](//stackoverflow.com/users/310726/martin) for pointing out that this code actually throws Observable instead of error.**

Answer (score 1):

Using modern rxjs with `pipe`, pipe the observable you're returning in the `retryWhen` operator with some logic that will throw an error if a certain condition is met.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-retrywhen-to-catch

```
import { interval, of, throwError, timer } from 'rxjs'; 
import { catchError, mergeMap, switchMap, retryWhen, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

const source = interval(1000);

const example = source.pipe(
  // simulate error
  switchMap(count => count > 3
    // this will be caught by retryWhen
    ? throwError('Error from source!')
    : of(count)
  ),
  retryWhen(err$ => err$.pipe(
    // display error from source
    tap(console.error),
    // i === index, AKA how many tries
    mergeMap((err, i) => i > 1
      // throw error, which is caught by catchError
      // or second argument to subscribe function if catchError not used
      ? throwError('Error from retry!')
      // wait specified duration before retrying
      : timer(3000)
    )
  )),
  catchError(err => of('There was an error, but we handled it. '))
);

example.subscribe(
  console.log,
  () => console.error('Nothing reaches this error handler because we used catchError')
);

/*

RESULT
0
1
2
3
Error from source!
0
1
2
3
Error from source!
0
1
2
3
Error from source!
There was an error, but we handled it. 

*/
```

Inspired by [this solution from learn-rxjs](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/error_handling/retrywhen.html#example-2-customizable-retry-with-increased-duration)